# raise() in while loop

Tags: c, signals, raise

I'm having a hard time with a little piece of code :

```
act_therm.sa_handler=handler_therm;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1,&act_thermom,NULL);
    while(1){
        raise(SIGUSR1);
        sleep(1);
        }
```

The code is compiling perfectly but the function handler_term is only launched once. It seems the behavior of the signal is reset to default after it's first raised.

Comment: I have a feeling that once the signal handler is called then the default action is restored unless you fiddle around with the other parts of the `act_therm` structure. Perhaps reading the manual page [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)

Comment: I tried adding
sigaction(SIGUSR1,&temp,NULL);
in the while loop and it's work. Like if sigaction work only one time...

Comment: The problem may also be in the handler itself, see [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks but that wouldn't explain why it work with the sigaction in the while loop

Comment: The fact that it works when you call sigaction repeatedly in the loop suggests to me that Ed is right and you have `SA_RESETHAND` set because you're not zeroing out your `struct sigaction` before setting up `sa_handler`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm introducting myself to interruption I don't really understand what SA_RESETHAND is for. My struct was declared like this :
struct sigaction act_therm;
followed by  act_therm.sa_handler=handler_therm;

Is there anything I should be doing differently ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't initialize the `act_thermom` structure correctly, read the manual and set all the fields to reasonable values... Have a look at `sa_flags`...

Comment: Signal handlers are to be set again for subsequent use i.e., once signal handler is invoked, set the signal handler again from within.  I am assuming that you wanted the signal handler to be invoked everytime the same signal is invoked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer. 
Is there any other solution that to put 
sigaction(SIGUSR1,&act_thermom,NULL);
right after each raise ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the complete answer in a book :

By declaring the structure just like this :

```
struct sigaction act_therm; 
act_therm.sa_handler=handler_therm;
```

The flag SA_RESETHAND is (by default) attached to the struct. Each time sigaction is called with it, It restore the default behavior of the signal.

There is two way to solve this problem :

- The bad one, which consists of redefining the behavior of the signal each time the signal is called with a sigaction
- Defining the complete structure (from the man) and creating sa_flags so that SA_RESETHAND is not called:

> ```
> struct sigaction {
>     void     (*sa_handler) (int);
>     void     (*sa_sigaction) (int, siginfo_t *, void *);
>     sigset_t   sa_mask;
>     int        sa_flags;
>     void     (*sa_restorer) (void);
> };
> ```